# Viewmodellocater unregister Viewmodels

Tags: viewmodel, viewmodellocator

I'm already seeking all day for a solution. I'm a MVVM-beginner and I have the following problem.
This is the code of my viewmodelLocator:

```
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            // Create design time view services and models
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create run time view services and models
            //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService,DataService>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, OleDbDataService>();
        }
  SimpleIoc.Default.Register<A>();
  SimpleIoc.Default.Register<B>();

    }


  public A a      {
    get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<A>(); }
  }

public B b    {
  get
  {
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<B>();
  }
}
```

After updating data from A, I want to open B and i do it in the following way:

```
private void A_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var bWindow = new bView();
  bWindow.Show();
  this.Close();
}
```

This works, but B uses data from A, and the updated data is not shown until I close my program and open it again. I've read that it has something to do with the Viewmodellocator and messages but as I am rather new to this, I don't exactly now how and/or where I need to do some "cleaning up".

Can anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A general tip, don't use viewmodellocator and messages as a beginner, because 99 of 100 it gets out of hand and you will most likely not learn how to utilize the MVVM pattern properly. Also, the messenger and locator has nothing to do with MVVM. Does the properties you set notify the ui with, e.g. A & B implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: yes they do.
to make it a little bit more clear... In A i have a list of cars (primary key numberplate), in B I want to fill a combobox with numberplates (a property of B, not a pk). But when i add a car (-> numerberplate) in A and go to B, B still loads the old list in the combobox.

Comment: This does the trick, but I have a feeling that it isn t the way it should be...

I've added a class CleanUp() in the ViewmodelLocator class:

   public static void CleanUp()
   {
      SimpleIoc.Default.Reset();
      ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

      if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
      {
        // Create design time view services and models
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
      }

Comment: else
      {
        // Create run time view services and models
        //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService,DataService>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, OleDbDataService>();
      }
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<A>();
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<B>();
         }

and in the button "Closing A" i've put

    private void A_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ViewModelLocator.CleanUp();
      
      var bWindow = new bView();
      bWindow.Show();
      this.Close();
    }

Does anyone know what the "proper" way is to achieve this?